# Como usar las sesiones en passport.js de nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, angular

Buen día, estoy trabajando en angular y nodejs con sus librerias
express,express-session,passport,passport-local, en elaborar un login
pero no se como se debe de usar las variables sesión con passport
correctamente, ya hice la configuración de passport.js y ya lo
inicialice dentro del server.js de esta manera:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

no estoy seguro si dentro de la ruta LOGIN() se crea un objeto  "user" para almacenar el valor como tal de la session en el request de esta manera:

```
router.post('/logout',(req,res)=>{
  UserModel.findOne({email:req.body.user} (err, result)=> {
     if(error){
       console.log(err)
     }
     else{
        req.user = result;
     }
  })
})

estoy confundido alguien podría aclarar  la duda, en explicar por favor, de antemano le agradezco.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada, es necesario que tengas claro el concepto de [`middleware`](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/using-middleware.html) en `expressjs`. Teniendo eso en cuenta todo lo que tienes que hacer es la configuración de `passportjs` correctamente.

Dado que no compartes en su totalidad la configuración que tienes, te compartiré un ejemplo que espero resuelva tus dudas sobre las sesión.

Primero que nada es necesario configurar `express session middleware` antes de poder manejar las sesiones con passportjs.

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Ahora configuramos `passport` middleware (es necesario que vaya después de  `express session middleware`).

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Ahora bien, si estas usando `passport-local` necesitas configurar una estrategia local. Este es un ejemplo, pero lo ideal es que hagas la consulta a tu DB para encontrar el usuario y validar la contraseña. `LocalStrategy` tiene como parámetros el usuario, la contraseña y un callback donde recibe el objeto del usuario si la autenticación fue correcta.

```js
 const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        (username, password, done) => {
            if(username === 'test@gmail.com' && password === '1234') {
                //Si es correcto regresa el objeto del Usuario
                return done(null, {username: 'test@gmail.com'});
            } else {
                //De lo contrario regresa falso
                return done(null, false);
            }
        }
 ));
```

> Nota: Tu petición **POST** debe enviar un objeto json que contenga los campos `username` y `password`, son los que maneja `passport` por defecto.

Para serializar y deserializar el usuario en la sesión, es necesario configurarlo. Para no serializar el objeto completo solo necesitamos un identificador, en este caso el `username` del usuario ó el `_id` de este mismo. En un ejemplo real `deserializeUser` haría una consulta a la BD para encontrar el usuario y pasarlo mediante el `done`.

```js
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
         //En este caso serializamos el username, pero es preferente usar el _id
        done(null, user.username);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((username, done) => {
       // Para este ejemplo estamos pasando el objeto User directamente
        done(null, {username: username});
    });
```

Ahora solo nos falta ponerlo en practica. En nuestra ruta `/login` usamos un middleware para autenticarnos mediante la función `passport.authenticate` usando la estrategia local previamente configurada. Además podemos configurar un `redirect` para ambos casos.

```
 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login-page',
        successRedirect: '/dashboard'
    }));
```

Por ultimo solo nos falta verificar si el usuario se encuentra autenticado, esto lo logramos usando un `middleware`. Si queremos cerrar sesión simplemente usamos `req.logout()` ya que la sesión del usuario se encuentra en el `request`.

```js
 function auth(req, res, next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
 }

 //Aqui vemos que usamos auth middleware
 app.get('/dashboard', auth, (req, res) => {
        res.render('dashboard');
 });

 //Ruta para cerrar la sesión
 app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/login');
 });
```

Comment: la verdad te agradezco mucho por la explicación esta genial,probe en postman la api rest y si funciona todo excelente,pero actualmente tengo un problema enorme el cual hace que el proyecto no sirva en su totalidad y sea pesimo,al usar angular como front_end el cierre de session no funciona req.logout(), sino que al intentar entrar en otra pagina aparece como activo el usuario, ya pase toda la noche en google y stackoverflow pero ningun metodo me funciona, si pudieras apoyarme con eso por favor te agregadezco mucho ya estoy frustado sueño

Comment: @juanlopez necesitarías abrir otra pregunta para darle seguimiento por ahí, te recomendaría que trates de exponer el problema en su totalidad, mediante código y errores para que sea mas rápido ayudarte.

Comment: lo hare gracias por la recomendacion